# How to work with already installed app in android using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can you you redirect user to google map with a address in flutter I mean i have address i want to create a link which on pressed redirect user to google map along with a specific address

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a package which can launch arbitrary URLs such as  [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) and possibly Deep Links ([iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html), [Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html)) if you want to communicate with other apps directly.

If the app you are targeting already has a deep link schema registered for it, you can use that schema to launch a "URL" to communicate with it. With maps, for example, you can use the `"geo:..."` schema on Android to launch a maps query directly in the Google Maps app. On iOS, you instead launch an HTTP request against the `"http://maps.apple.com/..."` URL. (More details on both can be seen in the links above.)

Alternatively, you can just use the [Google Maps browser-based URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started) and let the phone handle whether to open a browser or to forward it to a maps app. Personally I would recommend this one as it would be the simplest to implement:

```dart
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

...

final address = '1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043';
final url = Uri.encodeFull('https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$urlSafeAddress');

await launch(url);
```